# How to change the password of an account registerd in Firebase directly from the app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a mobile app using **Flutter** and I want to include the *forget password* feature.

So, the default method to change a password of an account registered inside **Firebase** is that, **Firebase** sends a link via an email to the email address of the corresponding account, and then the user presses on the link and he's prompted to change the password there.

What I want is that instead of changing the password from the browser, I want the user to do it inside the app directly. This method works simply by allowing the user to receive an **OTP** code in his email address that he must copy and paste into the app. After doing so, he'll be directed to the page where he can change the password of his account. Is there a way to do this with **Firebase**? If so, how? And is this feature (sending and **OTP** code) included in the free plan of **Firebase**?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not provide OTP based password reset feature.

Comment: which backend does it ?

Comment: which backend does it ?

Comment: Appwrite provides this feature but instead of sending a OTP it sends a secret key.
https://appwrite.io/docs/client/account?sdk=flutter-default

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is that instead of changing the password from the browser, I want the user to do it inside the app directly. This method works simply by allowing the user to receive an OTP code in his email address that he must copy and paste into the app.

OTP stands for One-Time Password. So this technique can only be used when you want to authenticate to Firebase using a Phone Number. Meaning that the user signs in using a one-time code contained in the SMS message. But that's not available in case of password changes. So you have to do it in your browser either on your computer or inside an email app on a mobile device.

Comment: Hey Mikelenjilo. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?